# COM interop working strangely

Tags: c#, com, interop

I'm writing an extension for a black-boxed native Win32 application using C#.
At runtime, the application will call a exported function named Register in the extesion and pass me a COM object.
And then I can do some job for the application through that COM object.

The problem is that this approach is working pretty weird. The COM interface has some methods:

```
[ComImport, Guid("75C46594-F6D6-4138-AC11-603C061ECC75")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IService
{
    [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint GetVersion();

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint GetLocale();

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    bool CheckVersion([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]int version);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
    IntPtr GetMainWindow();
}
```

And the Register function to be called by the host application:

```
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static bool Register([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]IService service)
    {
        Log("Executing Register");
        try
        {
            Log(service.GetVersion());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(e.ToString());
        }
        Log("Exiting Register");
        return true;
    }
```

When I call these method in my code, they sometimes return values not expected(GetLocale returns 0 or a random value that's not a locale ID, CheckVersion sometimes returns true and sometimes returns false etc.), sometimes even crash the main application(not actually crash, 
the UI is stilling responding but just stop doing it's job.). After I rebuild my code or restart the application, it may work.

So I tried another approach. I create a native library exposes functions of that COM interface, as a proxy, and the extension can operate the application through P/Invoking the native library.
It works fine, so I guess maybe there are some problems with my COM interop in C#. Can someone help me figure the problem out?

UPDATE:

The host application exposes several interfaces via COM and some of them do have multiple inheritance, but IService is indeed inherited from IUnknown, although some method of it return other COM objects to me. I didn't know that the order of methods matters. Maybe I can modify the definition in C# and try again.

And the author of the host application didn't provide any IDL file to me, just a Pascal header file:

```
type IService = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{75C46594-F6D6-4138-AC11-603C061ECC75}']
    function CheckVersion(Version: Integer): BOOL;
    function GetVersion: Longword; 
    function GetLocaleID: Longword;

    //These functions return other COM objects.
    function GetQueryManager: IQueryManager;
    function GetLogManager: ILogManager;
    //......

    function GetMainWindow: HWND;

    function ExecuteCommand(Cmd: Integer; Param: Pointer): BOOL;

    property LocaleID: Longword read GetLocaleID;

    //These are properties encapsulate some functions above.
    property QueryManager: IQueryManager read GetQueryManager;
    property LogManager: ILogManager read GetLogManager;
    property MainWindow: HWND read GetMainWindow;
    //......
  end;
```

Comment: Very vague, impossible to answer.  You'll have this kind of problem if IService inherits from some other kind of interface, other than IUnknown.  You'll have to declare the methods of that other interface first, C# does not support multiple inheritance.  A version problem is pretty standard too, just a mismatch between what you declared and what's actually implemented.  Wrong order of methods for example.

Comment: Do you have the COM IDL file for the 'IService' interface you are implementing - if so posting that might help get some answers.